# htmlspecialchars double encode not doing the trick

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a string that is coming from a drupal text area. The string in drupal contains html tags but when I print the string I do not see them.

This string is later going into `new SimpleXMLElement`, but since it has some problematic characters, I want to call on it:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8', false);
```

The problem is that afterward, my string looks as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2016-11-03"> 
    <Record userId="1" username="y" dmd:surveyId="1127463">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="x" entryKey="x &amp; x" text="x &amp; Life x"/>
```

This is a small portion of the string

Thus, when I am calling `SimpleXMLElement`on it I am getting

```
String could not be parsed as XML
```

i tried to avoid this with the `double_encode` value set to `false`, but it is not working.
I cannot remove the `SimpleXMLElementon` step, it breaks some of the drupal's functionality. 
What am I doing wrong?

____EDIT_____

as a check I replaced the htmlspecialchars with

```
$replace = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $string);
```

this is working fine.

Comment: Did you try to validate your xml in W3C validator ?

Comment: Yes. without this replacement, it is working fine (assuming I remove the & in it)

The issue is the added xml tags after calling htmlspecialchars

Comment: Did you try without ENT_QUOTES options ?

Comment: Will give it a try

Comment: same error, so it is not the ent_quotes

Comment: okay cool for str_replace , sometimes we don't need big functionnality to make it done haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$replace = str_replace('&', '&', $string);